"Мятро" у Утёсова
В песне старого извозчика Леонид Осипович произносит метро именно через я оба раза — мятро.  Интересно, почему так, вроде никаких подтверждений того, чтобы оно (а у него он ;)) через ять писалось, не нашёл.
Напомню строчки:
Но метро сверкнул перилами дубовыми,
Сразу всех он седоков околдовал.

Стилизация под старого извозчика.

Экспериментальный ответ
ПУТЕШЕСТВИЕ ВО ВРЕМЕНИ

Перенесемся сначала в 1914 год. Это совсем нетрудно, просто надо знать некоторые секреты)

Из современной художественной литературы:
  Мимо ехали коляски, некоторые очень красивые, сияющие 
  полировкой. Одна из них, с ярко-алыми спицами 
  остановилась. Молодой мужчина в смешной шляпе с узенькими 
  полями крикнул с козел:
  – Чего, барич, зря подметки топчешь? Садись, докачу. Если 
  не дале Лубянки, двугривенный всего.
  Лошадь у него была – просто заглядение. В гриву вплетены 
  разноцветные ленты, копыта сверкают лаком, а сиденье 
  красного бархата.
  – Чего в книжку уставился? – заманивал извозчик. – Не 
  сбежит твоя учеба. Эх, гори оно огнем, давай за гривенник, 
  себе в убыток! Для почину, первый нонешний седок будешь.
  Но не было у Ластика ни двугривенного, ни гривенника...
  – Спасибо, – вздохнул он. – Я пешком, мне близко.


Москва, 1938 год

Тогда насчитывалось несколько десятков извозчиков, а к началу 1940-го — лишь единицы.
https://yandex.ru/video/preview/8126117477461625008

Послушали песню?  Можно обратить внимание на то, что произношение у Л. Утесова вообще отличается от современного литературного, а в частности это касается редукции Е в безударных слогах, когда Е произносится как Я: мятро, преждя.

Это характерно для диалектного произношения. Детально этот вопрос можно посмотреть в статье:  Зона южнорусских говоров.
Мы же заглянем в школу советского периода. Там школьник читает стихи:
— Поздняя осень, грачи улятели...
— Но почему же — улятели?
— Клявать нечего, вот и улятели.


Диалог
— Правда, что у Леонида Утесова произношение в песнях 
отличается от современного? Или мне показалось? 
— Таки небольшой одесский акцент. 
— Он картавил. 
— Ви уже заметили его евгейский акцентик. 
— Правда. Но это не из-за "другой эпохи", это просто его 
персональный дефект речи. 



Любопытно:  Русский язык Одессы: чем он отличается от обычного русского языка.

— Леонид Утесов был одесситом? — А вы разве не знали? Подробнее: «Неполное низшее» образование и еще 9 любопытных фактов из жизни знаменитого одессита Леонида Утесова
Источник.
Утесов родился в еврейской семье, и до 17 лет его звали 
Лазарем Вайсбейном. Отец определил его в коммерческое 
училище, но вскоре его оттуда отчислили за плохую 
успеваемость и за то, что он то ли ударил, то ли облил 
чернилами одного из преподавателей. В дальнейшем в графе 
«Образование» он указывал: «Неполное низшее».


А теперь о самом слове метро. Этот вид транспорта официально называется метрополитен (мужской род), но в современном языке метро является существительным среднего рода.


Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
МЕТРО, неизм.; ср. = Метрополитен. Петербургское м. Ехать в м. Станция м. Войти в м.
Происхождение слова метро
Как только французские инженеры и дельцы назвали парижскую подземку «Метрополитен» — «Столичная», парижане тотчас же сократили это длинное слово до короткого — «метро́». От них оно перешло и к нам, и, хотя официальным названием и у нас является «Метрополитен имени В. И. Ленина», мы всюду — в Москве, Ленинграде, Киеве — называем этот вид городского транспорта коротким и удобным для языка словом «метро́».
  Метро́. Заимств. в Советскую эпоху из франц. яз., где métro 
  — сокращение métropolitain «метро» < «столичный» 
  (транспорт) < лат. metropolitanus, суф. производного от 
  metropolis «столица, главный город» < греч. metropolis — 
  тж., сложения mētēr «мать» и polis «город».

История создания песни

Очень увлекательное чтение, спасибо огромное!!! =)

Артем, а вам спасибо за вопрос!  Я многое узнала об Утесове, а то не знала почти ничего. И как любопытно было прислушаться к произношению. Про мятро я раньше знала, но там много других примеров. Вот что особенно интересно! Выязжаем, например.

Ага, и я вслед за вами только увидел эту Я и в других словах! ;)

Для меня это тоже было открытием))  Такой интересный образец живой диалектной речи. И песня очень хорошая, диалог со временем.  Лошадки, трамваи, первое метро. Кстати, метро было открыто в 1935 году, но вроде бы ср. род слова утвердился не сразу.   Я раньше думала,  что Утесов использует м. род для стилистики, а теперь сомневаюсь)

Да, мне тоже кажется, что именно утвердился не сразу. Вроде слышал такое, но не уверен)

Средний род у слова "метро", действительно, закрепился не сразу.
Поначалу метро был мужского рода. И это понятно и вполне логично, поскольку метро — это "урезанный" заимствованный метрополитен (м. р.).
• Вот здесь имеется изображение довоенной газеты — Советский Метро (№ 64 (172) от 15 мая 1936 г.). В то время это был метрополитен имени Л. М. Кагановича.
А вот пример из Нацкорпуса:
По мощности перевозок московский метро обогнал уже все метрополитены капиталистических стран (И. Катцен. Третья очередь метро // «Вечерняя Москва», 1937).
• Вопрос о метро был включен в задание олимпиады по русскому языку.

Задание 5. (11 баллов)
В «Песне старого извозчика» Леонид Утёсов пел:
Но метро сверкнул перилами дубовыми,
Сразу всех он седоков околдовал.
Какое слово в песне употреблено в устаревшем варианте? Какая грамматическая
категория претерпела в этом слове изменения? Как это определяется по приведённому тексту?
Объясните причины произошедшего изменения, рассмотрев историю происхождения
этого слова.

✦ Результаты поисков в печатных словарях:
ОС Д. Н. Ушакова (1938) — только метрополите́н;
ОС Д. Н. Ушакова и С. Е. Крючкова (1952) — метрополите́н (метро́) [в одной строке, род не указан];
ОС С. И. Ожегова и А. Б. Шапиро (1957) — метро́, нескл., с. (через шесть строк — метрополите́н, -а).
Предполагаю, что "родовая метаморфоза" произошла в конце сороковых — в самом начале пятидесятых годов.

Поставил тебе плюсик, Рим, но я ведь не про род, а про Я.

Спасибо, Артём! Да, конечно, ты спрашивал про Я. Но на этот вопрос хорошо ответила Sharon. Мне же захотелось ответить на комментарии (вроде бы ср. род слова утвердился не сразу) и развеять сомнения. Кроме того, я попыталась определить, когда это произошло.
